# returning different results form 3 tables when the query is written the same way

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have a form where I can select An Artist by his name or select a song and choose a date range and get statistics from it all, What i am trying to achieve is basically the below,

- get number of played
- get number of songs

Problems is both queries I am writing look the same, is there another way to tackle this in a better way ?

**here is the db structure**

3 tables

- **plays** : play_id | date
- **songs** : plid | aid
- **artist** : aid | artist_name

**Sample Variables**

```
$artist = SIA
$song = chandelier
$start_date = 2016-09-06
$end_date = 2016-09-07
```

**Sample DB Data**

**Plays Table**

- A- play_id = 12 | date = 2016-09-06
- B- play_id = 13 | date = 2016-09-07
- C- play_id = 14 | date = 2016-09-07

**Songs Table**

- A- plid = 12 | aid = 34
- B- plid = 12 | aid = 34
- C- plid = 13 | aid = 34
- D- plid = 14 | aid = 34
- E- plid = 14 | aid = 34

**artist Table**

- A- aid = 34 | artist_name = SIA

**Expected Result**

- A- number of Plays per artist = 3
- B- number of Songs per artist = 5

**Query for songs (this is working correctly and counting the songs correclty)**

```
$q2 = "
SELECT * 
  FROM songs s
  LEFT 
  JOIN plays p
    ON p.play_id = s.plid
  LEFT 
  JOIN artist a
    ON a.aid = s.aid
 WHERE (a.artist_name = '$artist' OR s.aid = '$song') 
   AND date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'";
```

**Query for plays (this one is returning same result as the query form the songs where it should return the number of plays by this artist)**

```
$q1 = "
SELECT * 
  FROM plays p
  LEFT 
  JOIN songs s
    ON s.plid = p.play_id
  LEFT
  JOIN artist a
    ON  a.aid = s.aid
 WHERE (a.artist_name= '$artist' OR s.aid = '$song') 
   AND date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'";
```

Comment: I've got deja vu all over again - plus, I recognise my own handwriting. What's going on?

Comment: You're negating your left joins in both cases by having a where condition that doesn't account for null.  Move the limits on artist_name or song to the joins and potentially date as well depending on what table it's in

Comment: @xQbert can you help me out here, how can this be done ?

Comment: I'm guessing date is in the plays table (even though it doesn't say so)

Comment: @Strawberry yes, date is in the plays table sorry not to mention it, but your smart

Comment: @xQbert this is actually an issue in the 2nd query, where the OP would like to get the play count, but by filtering on the songs eliminates all plays of the given artist that are not associated with a given song. In the 1st query the left joins can be replaced by inner joins.

Comment: @xQbert tried using Inner Join instead did not work

Comment: If you want to return the plays associated with an author, then why do you have a filter on songs in the 2nd query at all?

Comment: @Shadow cause it returns statistics for both artist or song by song

Comment: I got that, but by filtering on songs you get plays associated with a given artist or a given song, not plays associated with a given artist.

Comment: And if you are looking for a count, then why are you returning all fields from all the affected tables? To me it is absolutely not clear what you want to try to achieve here.

Comment: @Shadow i'm looking for a count in this query but looking for other data in other queries that are based on this one, even if i use COUNT in my query it doesn't work, What do you suggest doing ?

Comment: I cannot suggest anything because I have no idea what you want to achieve. Pls provide some sample data for the 3 tables (relevant fields only) and the expected results for the 2nd query based on the sample data and some description of what you want to achieve. Your current explanations are simply conflicting with each other. I suspect that you need to use count(distinct ...) function multiple times in the 2nd query to get the correct record count.

Comment: @Shadow there you go, question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing are caused by your data and the way you query it. It is clear from the sample data that a single play can have multiple songs.

This means, when you **list** the matching records from both the `plays` and the `songs` table, then the **number of records** returned will be determined by the `songs` table because it has the duplicate data.

To get the count of plays back, you need to count the number of **distinct** `play ids` returned by the query. Simple count would return 5 because of the duplications in the `song` table. Also, you do not need left joins as explained by @xQbert, so I just used inner joins, since you want matching plays only. I also removed the filtering on the songs, since you insists that the 2nd query should return the number of plays of a given artist. You are free to add that condition back.

```
$q1 = "
SELECT count(distinct p.play_id) as count_of_plays 
  FROM plays p
  INNER 
  JOIN songs s
    ON s.plid = p.play_id
  INNER
  JOIN artist a
    ON  a.aid = s.aid
 WHERE a.artist_name= '$artist' 
   AND date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at the second query...

```
$q1 = "
SELECT * 
  FROM plays p
  LEFT 
  JOIN songs s
    ON s.plid = p.play_id
  LEFT
  JOIN artist a
    ON  a.aid = s.aid
 WHERE (a.artist_name= '$artist' OR s.aid = '$song') 
   AND date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'";
```

may need to become...

```
$q1 = "
SELECT * 
  FROM plays p
  LEFT JOIN songs s
    ON s.plid = p.play_id
  LEFT JOIN artist a
    ON  a.aid = s.aid
  and (a.artist_name= '$artist' OR s.aid = '$song') 
 WHERE date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'";
```

What's happening is the LEFT joins generate the result set with the NULLs just as you want.  But then you had `(a.artist_name= '$artist' OR s.aid = '$song')`
in the where clause which would cause the NULLS generated in the left joins to be excluded from the results.

Try the above instead

Comment: tried it the result gave the number songs during that time frame but did not take the $artist or $song into consideration